# Bash console progress dialog with command output

Tags: bash, dialog

I have `dialog` installed, where I would like to have a nice progress dialog, like this:

```
+-------[ title ]--------+
|                        |
| +-[ console output ]-+ |
| | output line11      ^ |
| | output line12      | |
| | output line13      | |
| | output line14      # |
| | output line15      | |
| | output line16      v |
| +--------------------+ |
| #########80%#####::::: |
+------------------------+
```

So, for example when upgrading 5 packages in a distro, it shows the progress (here, 4 package is upgraded out of 5 ie. 80%), but shows the detailed output of the executed commands. Is this possible?

I suspect it is, but I cannot get a working solution with `--tailboxbg` and `--gauge`.

Comment: This kind of complex dialogs can be generated using [`gtkdialog`](http://code.google.com/p/gtkdialog/). Sorry, no detailed hints on exactly how, as I didn't managed yet to make it work on my system.

Answer (score 9):

Right, you can do it with `--gauge`:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare PACKAGES=("/etc/crontab"  "/etc/dmtab"  "/etc/fstab"  "/etc/inittab"  "/etc/mtab")
NUM_PACKAGES=${#PACKAGES[*]} # no. of packages to update (#packages in the array $PACKAGES)
step=$((100/$NUM_PACKAGES))  # progress bar step
cur_file_idx=0
counter=0
DEST=${HOME}
(
# infinite while loop
while :
do
    cat <<EOF
XXX
$counter
$counter% upgraded

$COMMAND
XXX
EOF
    COMMAND="cp ${PACKAGES[$cur_file_idx]} $DEST &>/dev/null" # sets/updates command to exec.
    [[ $NUM_PACKAGES -lt $cur_file_idx ]] && $COMMAND # executes command

    (( cur_file_idx+=1 )) # increase counter
    (( counter+=step ))
    [ $counter -gt 100 ] && break  # break when reach the 100% (or greater
                                   # since Bash only does integer arithmetic)
    sleep 10 # delay it a specified amount of time i.e. 1 sec
done
) |
dialog --title "File upgrade" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 70 0
```

This code in action:

[image: progress bar animation]

**Note**. This code actually copies those five files from `/etc/` into your `$HOME` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this possibility, however, I'd like to have a solution, where I can view the full output of the commands run.

Comment: 1) As `bash` does only integer arithmetic, is possible to not reach a total of 100 due to the truncated steps. 2) That indented here-document will fail to execute. 3) Initializing the counter with the number of packages is out of logic. 4) The parenthesis `()` around the `while` is pointless. 5) You have typo too: NUM_PACAKGES.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks for your clarification. I've tested the code and then updated.

Comment: Nice answer, but I would like to see all outputs, so in this case all the cp commands (very long list), and able to scroll back

Comment: I've tested the code and I see that only prints the commands really it does not copy anything, is it the expected behaviour of gauge widget?

Comment: I am amazed that nobody have noted that such a script only prints the "$COMMAND" but it does not execute it. If you'd want to really run it, $COMMAND must be below EOF. And you may want to copy ${PACKAGES[$cur_file_idx]} above second XXX ones characters.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about using `--tailboxbg` together with `--gauge`, but these have to listen to different file descriptors and be in the right order (`--tailboxbg` first)

Change double underscore `__MACROS__` with relevant content

```bsh
let total=__GET_MAX_COUNT__
let idx=0
let percent=0
let width=$(tput cols)
let height=$(tput lines)
log=$(mktemp --tmpdir dialog-progress.logXXX)

(for __LOOP__; do
cat <<EOF
XXX
$percent
Processing item $index ($percent %)
XXX
EOF
     let idx++
     let "percent = 100 * idx / total"
     __COMMAND__ >> $log
 done
) | dialog \
        --title "Dialog example progress with command output" \
        --begin 12 2 \
        --tailboxbg $log $((height - 14)) $((width - 6)) \
        --and-widget \
        --begin 2 2 \
        --gauge "Converting ..." 8 $((width - 6)) 0
```